# proxy_fcgi:error (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete. AH01075

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy-fcgi

I have a server running with:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache 2.4.18
- WORKER-MPM
- PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
- PHP-FPM
- OPcache 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3

On the browser there is an ajax script that each 5 sec sends a query to a php file to update a timestamp on the DB, this script works well on other servers, but here with not so many users it log the following error:

> [Mon Dec 05 09:11:39.575035 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7831:tid 140159538292480] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.30.197.200:64422] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: http://10.200....file.php

I have no idea what it is and how to fix it. I have searched the entire web and I didn't find much, any hint would be appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

I switch the error mode to debug and the full log for the error is this:

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465599 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465613 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465634 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] mod_proxy.c(1160): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0), referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465640 2016] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(879): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/sala.server.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465652 2016] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(886): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/sala.server.php, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465658 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] proxy_util.c(2160): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465663 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] proxy_util.c(2213): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/sala.server.php to localhost:8000, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465668 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] proxy_util.c(2250): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465735 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] proxy_util.c(2422): [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/sala.server.php to
 httpd-UDS:0, referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.465771 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] proxy_util.c(2701): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock (*)`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.480503 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.31.42.163:54432] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer: http://10.200.200.214/sala.php?sala=Unica`

`[Wed Dec 07 08:55:13.480533 2016] [proxy:debug] [pid 5461:tid 139687427467008] proxy_util.c(2175): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: You can test if these requests use chunked encoding. Perhaps you have this problem: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55475

Comment: Any other ideas? I had previously been using `location.reload` and ran into this same issue myself before and that seemed to work, but now I have a client that is causing these errors when uploading a 74KB file, I can upload a 200MB to the same place and its fine, so I find it hard to believe its a timeout issue.

Answer (score 5):

This answer does not address the question. But I came across this question while I'm having the same error. My issue was **I've refreshed my webpage programmatically (using `location.reload`) while multipart post request is sending** to the server.

Hope this would help someone.

Comment: Thanks @ruwan800, I was able to identify this beahviour on my web site. Multi post requests weren't finished (code 200) before I reload the page. We can clearly see this by using Browser Chrome dev tools > Network section.

Comment: And I can observe this on my home network which has 1Mb/s however I don't have any problem at my work place probably because network is way better.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to increase the default timeouts for this module:

`RequestReadTimeout header=10-20,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500`

Apache will close the connection if the header is not sent in 10 seconds, or in 20 seconds if the rate is lower than 500 bytes/sec.
Same for the body.

Therefore, instead of disabling the module, you can try to increase the seconds of the timeout.

`RequestReadTimeout header=10-40,MinRate=500 body=40,MinRate=500`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems that Apache2 module `reqtimeout` was causing this error: `AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)`

After disabling `reqtimeout` module with `sudo a2dismod reqtimeout` and reloading the apache server, everything seems to be working properly.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

Comment: I wouldnt recommend disabling reqtimeout , its a protection against attacks like slowloris