# Intermittent proxy error in Apache: "Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete" with "AH01110: error reading response"

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, varnish, mod-proxy

I'm using Apache 2.4.43 on CentOS 7.8 with Varnish 6 and PHP-FPM to serve a Magento 2 website.

Varnish listens on port 80. Apache listens on 8080 to serve content to Varnish, and also port 443 which proxies HTTPS requests to Varnish like so:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass         / http://127.0.0.1:80/
RequestHeader     set X-Forwarded-Port  "443"
RequestHeader     set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

This works for most requests, however occasionally (~10% of requests) I receive a 503 response from Varnish and in turn from Apache. The only error I can see in Apache's logs is this one:

```
[proxy_http:error] [pid 6719:tid 140054596265728] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client x.x.x.x:53760] AH01110: error reading response, referer: http://example.com
```

If I retry the request it usually works immediately although occasionally I'll have to refresh a few times before the request will be fulfilled. I notice this happens more frequently when making large batches of requests (i.e. a page with hundreds of external assets on it). I also notice it *seems* to happen with larger files and not with tiny ones.

I am guessing it could be some kind of timeout but I'm not sure which values to adjust or how to further debug this.

Things I have tried include the following:

- [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/870185/apache-restart-cause-proxy-httperror-pid-120502-70008partial-results-are) involves changing a module I'm not using (Forge Rock OpenAm).
- [This one](https://serverfault.com/questions/818891/proxy-fcgierror-70008partial-results-are-valid-but-processing-is-incomplete) suggests disabling `mod_reqtimeout` which I tried and it did not help.
- I have tried using `KeepAlive Off` which did not help.
- I tried putting `retry=0` at the end of `ProxyPass` which should apparently allow failed proxied connections to immediately retry but it didn't help

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing similar log entries. Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @tzvi We abandoned Magento 2 because it's so incredibly awful, so this problem went away with that. However I vaguely remember reading something about increasing the max response size in the proxy settings. Maybe the content was simply too large to be handled properly? Please leave a comment if you fix it for future users.